# Camel-Netty ReadTimeout Event handler not triggered

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am trying to use camel-netty for TCP Sync communication. I configured requestTimeout to be 5000 ms but event is not triggered. it is continuously waiting for response from server.

Note: With with default codec (textline codec) it is working fine.

Issue arises only when I add custom decoder / encoder to suit my requirement

Camel Version: 2.14.0
Netty Version - 3.9.4

Comment: Can you pls provide some information how the route looks like?

Comment: <route id="route1">
   <from uri="wmq:queue:queue1?disableReplyTo=true" />
   <process ref="byteResponseMessage" />
   <to uri="bean:messageLogger?method=log" />
   <to
    uri="netty:tcp://127.0.0.21:2626?decoders=#stxEtxDecoder,#byteToString&amp;encoders=#stxEtxEncoder&amp;sync=true&amp;requestTimeout=5000" />
<to uri="bean:messageLogger?method=fromlog" />
<process ref="validate"/>
</route>